# Ionic6 trigger stack modal from JS / TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic6

How can I trigger the modal from the script code instead through a button?
All examples I find in the [tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#sheet-modal) uses the modal trigger mechanism.

```
<ion-button id="open-modal" expand="block">Open Sheet Modal</ion-button>

  <ion-modal #modal trigger="open-modal" [initialBreakpoint]="0.25" [breakpoints]="[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]">
```

I cant find or properly search for this feature.

Answer (score 2):

In the same tutorial, they [mention](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#using-isopen) the `isOpen` property which takes in a boolean value. So, your code would look something like this:

```
<ion-modal [isOpen]="isModalOpen" [initialBreakpoint]="0.25" [breakpoints]="[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]">
```

And your method in the component would be:

```
isModalOpen = false;

  setOpen(isOpen: boolean) {
    this.isModalOpen = isOpen;
  }
```

One disadvantage of using this approach is that you will have to manually set the `isModalOpen` back to `false`, even when one closes the modal using the background.

> `isOpen` uses a one-way data binding, meaning it will not
> automatically be set to false when the modal is dismissed. Developers
> should listen for the ionModalDidDismiss or didDismiss event and set
> isOpen to false

Trying to open a modal when its `isOpen` property is still set to true, will not do anything even if the modal is physically/visually closed. So be careful.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll check it out.